# Verificar si un año es Bisiesto o no y guardarlo en un Array, luego, Imprimir los que son Bisiestos y los que no

Tags: c#, año-bisiesto

Se requiere un programa que permita guardar en un vector los años ingresados por un usuario de acuerdo al criterio si el año es bisiesto o no.

Diseñe una aplicacion de consola que permita ingresar a un usuario n cantidad de años y posteriormente clasifiquelos en año bisiesto o año NO bisiesto. Su programa debe preguntar cuantos años se desean ingresar, por ejemplo, si el usuario ingrsesa 20 debe permitir ingresar 20 años, recuerde que debe clasificarlos por año bisiesto o año NO bisiesto.
De acuerdo a su validacion de año bisiesto o No, declare un vector para guardar años bisiestos y otro vector para guardar años no bisiestos.
Finalmente visualice en pantalla los 2 vectores,  con los años clasificados

Mi codigo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int año, op, i;
            int[] anoBisiesto;
            int[] anoNoBisiesto;


            Console.WriteLine("Parcial #2 - Jesus Palma");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("Clasificación de año bisiesto y no bisiesto. \n");
            Console.Write("¿Cuántos años desea ingresar para clasificar?: ");
            op = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\n");

            for (i = 0; i < op; i++)
            {
                anoBisiesto = new int[op];
                anoNoBisiesto = new int[op];

                Console.Write("Ingrese un año: ");
                año = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (año % 4 == 0 && (año % 100 != 0 || año % 400 == 0))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("El año " + año + " Si es bisiesto \n");
                    anoBisiesto[op] = año;

                }
                else
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("El año " + año + " No es bisiesto \n");
                    anoNoBisiesto[op] = año;
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < op; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("DATOS DEL VECTOR: ");
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------- \n");
                Console.Write("" + anoBisiesto[op] + " ");
            }
        }
```

Pero a la hora de imprimir los datos que guardé en el array, me dice "Variable local no asignada"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta era bastante sencillo, para la dimensión del array, cuando se muestra "Cuantos años" deseamos ingresar se guardan en la variable `op` , luego, igualo `numeros` con `op` , y el Array (Arreglo) lo declaro como entero de la siguiente forma: `int[] añosBisiestos = new int[numeros];` y el otro `int[] añosNoBisiestos = new int[numeros];` , lo que hace esto es que los Array añosBisiestos y añosNoBisiestos tienen como dimensión la cantidad de años que se ingresarán, y, si es bisiesto, se guarda `añosBisiestos[i] = año;` el año dentro del array `añosBisiesto` y dentro de este, la `i` para indicar la posición del año, por ejemplo: añosBisiesto[0], añosBisiesto[1], etc, y al final, para mostrar los datos guardados en el array, se hace un ciclo idéntico al primero y se imprime el array: `Console.Write("[" + añosBisiestos[i] + "] \n");`

> ```
> Código final abajo:
> ```

```
using System;

namespace parcial2JesusPalma
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int año, op, i, numeros;


            Console.WriteLine("Parcial #2 - Jesus Palma");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("Clasificación de año bisiesto y no bisiesto. \n");
            Console.Write("¿Cuántos años desea ingresar para clasificar?: ");
            op = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            numeros = op;

            int[] añosBisiestos = new int[numeros];
            int[] añosNoBisiestos = new int[numeros];

            Console.Write("\n");

            for (i = 0; i < numeros; i++)
            {

                Console.Write("\n Ingrese un año: ");
                año = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                if (año % 4 == 0 && (año % 100 != 0 || año % 400 == 0))
                {
                    
                    añosBisiestos[i] = año;
                    Console.WriteLine("El año " + año + " Si es bisiesto");
                }

                else
                {
                    
                    añosNoBisiestos[i] = año;
                    Console.WriteLine("El año " + año + " No es bisiesto");
                }

            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("\n DATOS INGRESADOS: \n");
            for (i = 0; i < numeros; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("AÑOS BISIESTOS INGRESADOS: \n");
                Console.Write("[" + añosBisiestos[i] + "] \n");
                Console.WriteLine("AÑOS NO BISIESTOS INGRESADOS: \n");
                Console.Write("[" + añosNoBisiestos[i] + "] \n");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenes que sacar la variable fuera del for e inicializarla, porque puede no entrar al for y nunca se inicializaria y eso es el error que se puede producir y te marca el visual studio.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Parcial #2 - Jesus Palma");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("Clasificación de año bisiesto y no bisiesto. \n");
        Console.Write("¿Cuántos años desea ingresar para clasificar?: ");
        op = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("\n");

        anoBisiesto = new int[op]; // fuera del for, y queda disponible para todo el metodo.

        for (i = 0; i < op; i++)
        {
            anoNoBisiesto = new int[op];

            Console.Write("Ingrese un año: ");
            año = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (año % 4 == 0 && (año % 100 != 0 || año % 400 == 0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El año " + año + " Si es bisiesto \n");
                anoBisiesto[op] = año;

            }
            else
            {

                Console.WriteLine("El año " + año + " No es bisiesto \n");
                anoNoBisiesto[op] = año;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < op; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("DATOS DEL VECTOR: ");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------- \n");
            Console.Write("" + anoBisiesto[op] + " ");
        }
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, muy acertada y concreta, +1 en calificación.

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo una alternativa, podrías usar la **función** **IsLeapYear** que pertenece a la **clase** **DateTime**, esta función devuelve **true** en caso de que el año sea bisiesto y **false** en caso contrario. Y además usar **Linq**:

```
int año, op;

Console.WriteLine("Parcial #2 - Jesús Palma");
Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
Console.WriteLine(" ");
Console.WriteLine("Clasificación de año bisiesto y no bisiesto. \n");
Console.Write("¿Cuántos años desea ingresar para clasificar?: ");
op = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("\n");
int[] arregloAños = new int[op];

for(int i = 0; i < op; i++)
{
   Console.Write("Ingrese un año: ");
   año = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   arregloAños[i] = año;
}
```

Hasta aquí lo que hacemos es declarar un arreglo de años el cual nos va a guardar todos los años que ingresemos sin importar si es o no bisiesto.

Ahora usaremos **Linq** para determinar los años que son bisiestos y los que no son bisiestos.

```
var bisiestos = (from a in arregloAños
                 where DateTime.IsLeapYear(a)
                 select a).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("Años bisiestos");

foreach(var b in bisiestos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());      
}
```

Aquí lo que se hace es una consulta **Linq**, la cual va a recorrer todos los años de arreglo original e irá preguntando si cada año es bisiesto, retornando un array con todos los años bisiestos.

Posteriormente mediante un **ciclo foreach** se recorren todos los elementos del **arreglo bisiestos** y se van imprimiendo en consola.

Para los no bisiestos sería similar:

```
var noBisiestos = (from a in arregloAños
                   where DateTime.IsLeapYear(a) == false
                   select a).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("Años no bisiestos");

foreach(var b in noBisiestos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());      
}
```

Esta vez la consulta **Linq** nos devolverá los no bisiestos y los imprimimos usando igualmente un **ciclo foreach**.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Excelente Japv, esa función no la sabía y la verdad si funcionó muy bien, gracias!